# Sitecore Custom form element does not follow bootstrap div "form-group" structure

Tags: sitecore-forms

We have created a new date picker field with dropdown options for Month, Year and Day by following the article [Sitecore Guide](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/93/sitecore-experience-manager/walkthrough--creating-a-custom-form-element.html)

The field data is being saved properly, but we are facing the below issues

- When set to mandatory, the field validation does not work.
- All the out of the box elements are wrapped with "" and "required field" if marked as mandatory. But the custom element renders with out the div and we are unable to figure out where to set that up.

Attached the screenshot, where the OOTB elements are rendered within div form-group class and custom element elements are not.
[image]

Could you help in understanding how the bootstrap div structure is generated for the forms and other elements and how can the same be done for the custom fields ?

Here is the sample code for the field cshtml

```
 @using Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Html

@model DatePickerViewModel


@{var htmlAttributes = new Dictionary<string, object>()
{
        { "class", "form-control" }
  };
}

<label for="@Html.IdFor(m => Model.Value)" class="@Model.LabelCssClass">@Html.DisplayTextFor(t => Model.Title)</label>
<input type="date" style="display:none;" id="@Html.IdFor(m => Model.Value)" @if (Model.Min.HasValue) { <text> min="@Model.Min.Value.ToString(Model.DateFormat)" </text> } @if (Model.Max.HasValue) { <text> max="@Model.Max.Value.ToString(Model.DateFormat)" </text> } @if (Model.Value.HasValue) { <text> value="@Model.Value.Value.ToString(Model.DateFormat)" </text> } name="@Html.NameFor(m => Model.Value)" class="wfmDatebox @Model.CssClass" data-sc-tracking="@Model.IsTrackingEnabled" data-sc-field-name="@Model.Name" data-sc-field-key="@Model.ConditionSettings.FieldKey" @Html.GenerateUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes(m => Model.Value) />

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <div class="input-group" style="width:100%">
            <div class="input-group-addon">@Model.DayTitle</div>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Day, Model.Days, htmlAttributes)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <div class="input-group" style="width:100%">
            <div class="input-group-addon">@Model.MonthTitle</div>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Month, Model.Months, htmlAttributes)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <div class="input-group" style="width:100%">
            <div class="input-group-addon">@Model.YearTitle</div>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Year, Model.Years, htmlAttributes)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.Value)
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What is the content of your field cshtml file?

Comment: Hello @MarekMusielak , I have updated the question and added the cshtml content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had similar scenario and in our case the solution was to wrap the field content in

```
@{
    var requiredClass = "";
    if(Model.Required){
        requiredClass = "required-field";
    }
}

<div class="form-group @Model.CssClassSettings.CssClass @requiredClass">
    YOUR CSHTML HERE
</div>
```

so in your case it should be something like:

```
@{
    var requiredClass = "";
    if(Model.Required){
        requiredClass = "required-field";
    }
    
    var htmlAttributes = new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        { "class", "form-control" }
    };
}

<div class="form-group @Model.CssClassSettings.CssClass @requiredClass">
    <label for="@Html.IdFor(m => Model.Value)" class="@Model.LabelCssClass">@Html.DisplayTextFor(t => Model.Title)</label>
    <input type="date" style="display:none;" id="@Html.IdFor(m => Model.Value)" @if (Model.Min.HasValue) { <text> min="@Model.Min.Value.ToString(Model.DateFormat)" </text> } @if (Model.Max.HasValue) { <text> max="@Model.Max.Value.ToString(Model.DateFormat)" </text> } @if (Model.Value.HasValue) { <text> value="@Model.Value.Value.ToString(Model.DateFormat)" </text> } name="@Html.NameFor(m => Model.Value)" class="wfmDatebox @Model.CssClass" data-sc-tracking="@Model.IsTrackingEnabled" data-sc-field-name="@Model.Name" data-sc-field-key="@Model.ConditionSettings.FieldKey" @Html.GenerateUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes(m => Model.Value) />

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="input-group" style="width:100%">
                <div class="input-group-addon">@Model.DayTitle</div>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Day, Model.Days, htmlAttributes)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="input-group" style="width:100%">
                <div class="input-group-addon">@Model.MonthTitle</div>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Month, Model.Months, htmlAttributes)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="input-group" style="width:100%">
                <div class="input-group-addon">@Model.YearTitle</div>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Year, Model.Years, htmlAttributes)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.Value)
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Marek for the quick response. This is what we were looking for.

Comment: We have another problem related to the bootstrap structure on the forms, where the "form-section" and "row" div structure is not generated on one of the lower environments. We have installed the form package from another environment where its working fine. 

On "Form Section" field, the 2 div structure is missing 
<div class="form-section"><div class="row">

Could you let me know, what could be the possible root cause for this ?

Comment: Best create another question and someone will help you if they can

Comment: Thanks again for your quick help :)